# How to nest a sub TabMenu inside a Primefaces TabMenu using composite components of JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I have two Primefaces TabMenus which I want to nest. There is an outer TabMenu with 3 tabs. the innerTabMenu is part of Tab 1 from the Outer TabMenu.

I am using templates for each tab xhtml file. In the template I insert the composite component(composite component defines the TabMenu ) using  tags. In each xhtml file representing the tabs I use the  tags to set the attribute for each tab. And I have defined the navigation flow in faces-config.xml.The same format is followed for both the outer and inner tabs.Separately these work fine. I need to know how can I nest these two tabMenus using composite components.

Comment: Have you tried to do it? If so, show us.

Comment: Please provide code of your current solution (http://sscce.org).

Comment: I figured out the problem by adding the composite component for the innerTabMenu in the same <ui:define> tag where I was adding the outerTabMenu composite component. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem by adding the composite component for the innerTabMenu in the same  tag where I was adding the outerTabMenu composite component. Thanks!